# How to convert numbers in a String to an int?

Tags: java

I have a String that accepts numbers from user input and I want to calculate the sum of all the numbers in a String.

An example of a sample output will look like this,

Enter an integer: 1234
The sum is 10.

Comment: We dont provide code! Why not try it yourself?

Comment: How about showing the code you've written and asking a specific question about what you think is not working in it?

Comment: Java 8: `string.chars().sum()-'0'*string.length()`. Of course you should verify that the input is valid first, e.g. `string.matches("[0-9]+")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer");
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.lentgth(); i++){
   sum+=Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(i)+"");
}
System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: There is not a method called parse() in the class Integer. Perhaps you mean parseInt() ?

Comment: @Alboz What the is wrong with the answer. Answer is correct, the only reason you downvote it is that the guy who asked is lazy.